# Clar's rule of polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, theoretical-chemistry, resonance, aromaticity

[Clar's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycyclic_aromatic_hydrocarbon#Physicochemical_properties_and_bonding)  states that the Kekulé resonance structure with the largest number of disjoint aromatic π-sextets, i.e., benzene-like moieties, is the most important for characterization of properties of polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbons (PAHs). What is the reason for the validity of Clar's rule?

I mean why does polybenzoid structures follow Clar's rule (what is the mechanism lying behind it) and what is the reason for the stability of these structures?

Comment: And what reason other then "it works" would you like? These are just some rules of thumb not a Relativity Theory.

Comment: what is clar's rule? Please add more detail into your question.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3982536/

Comment: @Mithoron i just wanted to know why it works, the mechanism behind it, and not to prove its validity

Comment: @NilayGhosh i saw this article but it doesn't address the mechanism behind the rule.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb i edited the question

Comment: OK, we''ll see if it's reopened. I guess MOT can give some more insight then simple rule about this.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16562/is-pyrene-aromatic-despite-failing-h%c3%bcckels-rule

Comment: You might agree that it is a good and reasonable starting point.