# Cross-conjugation and aromaticity in pyrene

Tags: quantum-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, molecular-structure, resonance, aromaticity

I have read about non-huckel double bonds and clar's rule, but what made me confuse is that huckel's perception **gives me the feeling** that central bonds in polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbons (ex: pyrene) is simply minimally affecting  aromaticity or even dropped off, while clar's rule shows different resonance forms which in total makes a complete sextet formed in each ring of pyrene.

1. So how could i resolve this issue?
2. what would happen to aromaticity if simply the central double bond was not in the pyrene?
3. is there any cross-conjugation involved? and how would cross-conjugation affect aromaticity?

Comment: have you seen https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16562/is-pyrene-aromatic-despite-failing-h%C3%BCckels-rule

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Yes but the answers don't show the way both rules (clar and huckel) are applicable in the same molecule (pyrene) although they don't **seem** so. And they don't show the effect of central double bonds on **stability** as well as aromaticity and whether **cross-conjugation** is involved or not?